# Отправить запрос на ip через curl

Tags: php, curl, postman

Пробую отправить запрос на ip нужного сайта через `curl`. Вначале отправил через постман такой запрос:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.1.1.1
Host: test.ru
```

URL : `https://1.1.1.1/`.  Доменное имя сайта указано в заголовке `Host`. Никаких проблем - мне вернулось содержимое `html` страницы. Но когда я попробовал перенести в `php` что то пошло не так :

```
$ch = curl_init('1.1.1.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('host:test.ru')); 
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
```

В результате очень долго грузит и в итоге ничего (null) не возвращает. Пробовал с указанием порта - не работает. Запрос просто не отправляется. В чем может быть дело ?

UPD
Добавил вывод ошибок  `$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );` Получил :

> Failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 port 80: Connection timed out

поставил порт 443 - `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);` ошибка осталась. Причем `url` согласно информации     `$info = curl_getinfo($ch);` записывается как `["url"]=> string(22) "http://1.1.1.1/"`принудительно указать вместо `ip` адреса `https://ip..` не получается, та же ошибка :

> Failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 port 443: Connection timed out

Но в постмане (+ telnet) же все отправлялось, не понимаю в чем дело. Даже не пингуется сервер `ping 1.1.1.1`

Comment: `phpinfo();` curl присутствует?

Comment: @StereoFlo присутствует и другие запросы отправляет верно.

Comment: так возможно проблема с SSL. Попробуйте добавить `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); `. У меня ваш код работает.

Comment: @Эдуард едва ли дело в заголовке. при замене ip на доменное имя проблема пропадает.

Comment: @StereoFlo Попробовал установить `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` и `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` в 0 - проблема осталась.

Comment: @StereoFlo просто отваливается по таймауту

Comment: Есть подозрение, что ваша проблема связана с PHP, попробуйте проверить на другом сервере, если есть возможность. Как я сказал выше, ваш код у меня работает.

Comment: @StereoFlo к сожалению такой возможности нет. Какая может быть проблема с php, версия ? у меня 5.6.38

Comment: Почитайте здесь http://php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Comment: @StereoFlo там ничего нет по моей проблеме. На phpfiddle код тоже не работает хотя там версия 7 php

Comment: На phpfiddle, я уверен, курл намеренно отключен.

Comment: @StereoFlo нет он работает, по крайней мере с доменным именем вместо ip.

Answer (score 0):

Точно такой код как у вас работает корректно:

```
$ch = curl_init('1.1.1.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('host:test.ru')); 
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
```

Показывает HTML код заглушки Cloudflare:

```
<title>Origin DNS error | test.ru | Cloudflare</title>
```